# How to filter basic English words from a word list in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Tool that I use:** Google Sheets (I do not use Google Apps Script in this case.)

**Objective for this question:**
I would like to exclude basic English words from a list of words by using Google Sheets function. Purpose of this questions is that I would like to do text mining with google sheets.

**Current situations:**

There is a column that has some english words.
This table is gained from these sentences below.

- I have a dog named Ocean.
- I have a book titled *Rosetta*.
- I do this.
- I do that.

Sheet name: Sheet1

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Words. | Word count |
| 2 | i | 4 |
| 3 | have | 2 |
| 4 | do | 2 |
| 5 | a | 2 |
| 6 | dog | 1 |
| 7 | book | 1 |
| 8 | named | 1 |
| 9 | ocean | 1 |
| 10 | titled | 1 |
| 11 | rosetta | 1 |
| 12 | . | 4 |
| 13 | that | 1 |
| 14 | this | 1 |

From such a table, I would like to filter some basic English words such as *i*, *have*, *do*, *a*, and "*.*" .

If it is about filtering small number of values, I know this solution. I can use filter () function to filter *i*, *have*, *do*, *a*, and "*.*" .

```
= filter (A2:12, A2:12<>"i",A2:A12<>"have", A2:A12 <> "do", A2:A12<>"a", A2:A12 <>".")
```

However, if it is about to filter more values, this filter function becomes longer. That will lack readability.

```
 = filter (A2:12, A2:12<>"i",A2:A12<>"have", A2:A12 <> "do", A2:A12<>"a", ..., A2:A12 <>".")
```

In order to prevent it, I prepared the following list that has basic English words.

Sheet Name: Sheet2

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | i |
| 2 | you |
| 3 | he |
| 4 | she |
| 5 | we |
| 6 | they |
| 7 | but |
| ... | ... |
| 1000 | . |

With this above list, I tried to filter the values from Sheet!A1:A but it did not work.

Perform this function at C column of Sheet1.

```
=filter(A2:A, A2:A<>Sheet2!A2:A)
```

As a result of function, this created nothing. This function did not exclude values that specified at Sheet2.

**Questions:**
In order to realize this feature with some combination of google sheet functions, how should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=filter(A2:A, not(regexmatch(A2:A, textjoin("|", 1, Sheet2!A2:A))))
```

and see if that works? If not, please share a copy of your spreadsheet so we can have a closer look.

UPDATE: because of the special meaning some punctuation marks have in regular expressions it would be best **not** to include them in the list (sheet2) and add them before the textjoin() in a 'character class). That would make the formula look like this

```
=filter(A2:A, not(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"[.,:?]|"&textjoin("|", TRUE, Sheet2!A2:A))))
```

Also make sure that the second parameter of textjoin() is set to 'TRUE'.

[image]

Comment: Should it be =filter(A2:A, not(regexmatch(A2:A,textjoin("|", 1, Sheet2!A2:A)))) ?

Comment: Of course, @TomSharpe. I edited my aswer. Thanks !!

Comment: @JPV Thank you for your prompt answer! I tried your formula, but it appears that it did not work. Could you take a look at my Answer below for screenshots?

Comment: @Kos: can you share a copy of your spreadsheet? That will make it easier to help you out.

Comment: @JPV Thanks for your reply. This is the copy of my spreadsheet. If you need anything else, please kindly let me know. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/172ooFtw2cbnXzfFP54c8te5m06w9M0U6X6ZS_-4hdUk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JPV I'm impressed at your help! Thank you very much. I almost got what I need. In addition to it, I modified your help as below. This helped me to get what I exactly want.  I appreciate your detailed help here!    filter(A2:A, not( REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"[.,:?]|^("&textjoin("|", TRUE, Sheet2!A2:A)&")$")))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your prompt help! I tried your suggested formula, but unfortunately it could not work.

[This shows "No matches are found in FILTER evaluation."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4RMi.png)

This is the sheet2. It has the list of words:

[The list of words that I want to exclude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8EWk.png)

Based on your suggestion, I tried to look at each formula's meaning.

textjoin("|", 1, Sheet2!A2:A) is a way to prepare "OR" expression.
REGEXMATCH(A2:A, textjoin("|", 1, Sheet2!A2:A)) is a way to return TRUE or FALSE.

[textjoin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6c2L.png)
[regexmatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4SoN.png)

Because this regex match returned #REF error. I modified the formula like below;

[modified regexmatch formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTyDT.png)

This returned FALSE as a result. Based on these, I replaced the suggested formula like below:

```
=filter(A2:A, not(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,textjoin(" | ", 1, Sheet2!A2:A))))
```

added two spaces around "|"

This formula returned values, however it looks like the returned values in C column do not exclude the words specified in Sheet2.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOeHH.png)

In order to exclude values that are specified in Sheet2, what should I do?